# How to Insert data into column from axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, axios

My reactjs app was build using function based and currently tried to showing user datas from my APIs in datagrid form. And when i test my code, The console result give me an error, it's say "**TypeError: destroy is not a function**". maybe because i don't know exactly how to do it. Here's my reactjs part code.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
      { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
      { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
      {
        title: 'Birth Place',
        field: 'birthCity'
      },
    ]
  });

  useEffect(() => 
    Axios.get('http://localhost/api/User/GetUsers')
    .then(response => {     
      setState(response.data);

      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);})    
  );
```

Am i missing something ?

Comment: I think this error due to memory leak so can you try to add dependency in useEffect with blank array [ ] so it will call once.

Answer (score 2):

This error due to memory leak happens due to multiple time useEffect called and setState so you can define dependency by blank array [] in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost/api/User/GetUsers')
    .then(response => {     
      setState(response.data);

      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);})    
  },[]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the error was gone now but my datagrid still empty

Comment: Dependency array is not the only problem here. OP returns the fetch part from `useEffect` since there isn't any arrow function body block. `return` part is invoked at unmount. It is worth mentioning.

Comment: That syntax have not followed and added to solution so let me edit this

Comment: I've already seen that you added the right syntax but maybe OP has not realized it. This is why I've made my comment :)

Comment: :) what is OP? Can you please guide properly

Comment: Oh, it is "Original Poster", means the owner of the question here :) You can add an explanation about not returning like that but instead use the syntax as you do in your answer.

Comment: Ohh I see Thanks :)

Comment: so i need to add arrow function body block in my code ? okay